# Syncing .git directory in pycharm

Tags: git, pycharm

I'm developing with pycharm locally on my windows 10 machine. and have a guest VM machine with ubuntu which contain my remote deployment server. I'm using SFTP for syncing between the two environments. my problem is that it seems like pycharm uses a local windows based git to locally manage the git operations. so its seems there are two seperate .git directories, a local one and a remote one.

My question is,  what if i do some stuff on the remote machine like "git checkout otherbranch" or any other commit operation which is done remotely and manually. i would like the remote and the local .git to be always synced.

now i know its not syncing because of this configuration:

[image]

And I've been wondering if removing the ".git" directory is a bad/dangerous practice? if so, what would be the best way to achieve my goal?

Any help is much appreciated!